# Repository of trainers

Tags: c#, sql, repository, asp.net-core

This is my first asp.net core web api and i did followed the Repository pattern but i don't know whether this approach is good practice.

```
public class TrainerRepo : IRepoTrainer
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public TrainerRepo(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public IDbConnection dbConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("MyConnString"));
        }
    }

    public List<Trainer> GetTrainers()
    {
        string sql = "select trainer_id,trainer_name from trainer";
        using(IDbConnection conn = dbConnection)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var res = conn.Query<Trainer>(sql).ToList<Trainer>();
            conn.Close();
            return res;
        }

    }

    public int NewTrainer(Trainer trainer)
    {
        string sql = "insert into trainer ( trainer_name) values ( @name)";
        using(IDbConnection conn = dbConnection)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var res = conn.Execute(sql, param: new
            {
                //id = trainer.trainer_id,
                name = trainer.trainer_name
            });
            conn.Close();
            return res;
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> updateTrainer(Trainer trainer)
    {
        string sql = "update trainer set trainer_name = @tname where trainer_id = @tid";
        using(IDbConnection conn = dbConnection)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var res = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, param: new { tname = trainer.trainer_name, tid = trainer.trainer_id });
            conn.Close();
            return res;
        }
    }

    public int deleteTrainer(int id)
    {
        string sql = "delete from trainer where trainer_id=@trainerId";
        using(IDbConnection conn = dbConnection)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var res =  conn.Execute(sql, param: new { trainerId = id });
            conn.Close();
            return res;
        }
    }

}
```

IRepoTrainer interface

```
public interface IRepoTrainer
{
    List<Trainer> GetTrainers();
    int NewTrainer(Trainer trainer);
    Task<int> updateTrainer(Trainer trainer);
    int deleteTrainer(int id);
}
```

my problem is that reuse of following code block, is it good practice ?

```
 using(IDbConnection conn = dbConnection)
   {
    conn.Open();
    //
    conn.Close();
    return res;
   }
```

Comment: You could make the repo disposable. Open the connection only if it is closed, and close it when the repo is disposed.

Comment: It has been suggested in docs to not pass `IConfiguration` around for injection. Try creating a `IConnectionFactory` or just have a connection injected into the repo

Comment: Could you provide me some example code please ! @Nkosi

Comment: @Nkosi I wouldn't do it (the repo disposable) becuase then you cannot use this repository with DI easily. You would need to get a new instance each time. It's better when the APIs control connections themselfes. It would also be difficult to use multiple ORMs per repository.

Comment: @Nkosi - those comments sound like they are worth writing in an answer (you'll probably get some votes, too!).  Please do so - comments are supposed to be for improving the question, not answering it!

Comment: @TobySpeight :-)

Comment: @Nkosi if there only was a usage-friendly alternative to not passing `IConfiguration` around for injection... it's too convenient ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been suggested in docs to not pass `IConfiguration` around for injection. Try creating a `IConnectionFactory` or just have a connection injected directly into the repo

Something like

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
   IDbConnection CreateConnection();
}
```

and its implementation for your class would look something like this

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory {
    private readonly string dbConnectionString;

    public SqlConnectionFactory(string dbConnectionString) {
        this.dbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() {
        return new SqlConnection(this.dbConnectionString);
    }
}
```

it would be registered in startup

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnString");
services.AddScoped<IDbConnectionFactory, SqlConnectionFactory>(_ => new SqlConnectionFactory(connectionString));

//...
```

and injected

```
public class TrainerRepo : IRepoTrainer {
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory factory;

    public TrainerRepo(IDbConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public List<Trainer> GetTrainers() {
        string sql = "select trainer_id,trainer_name from trainer";
        using(IDbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
            connection.Open();
            var res = connection.Query<Trainer>(sql).ToList<Trainer>();
            connection.Close();
            return res;
        }
    }

    //...
```

The repeated code can also be generalized

```
T Invoke<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> func) {
    using(IDbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
        connection.Open();
        var res = func(connection);
        connection.Close();
        return res;
    }
}

async Task<TResult> InvokeAsync<TResult>(Func<IDbConnection, Task<TResult>> func) {
    using(IDbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
        connection.Open();
        var res = await func(connection);
        connection.Close();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Which changes the previous examples to

```
public List<Trainer> GetTrainers() {
    string sql = "select trainer_id,trainer_name from trainer";
    return Invoke(connection => connection.Query<Trainer>(sql).ToList<Trainer>());
}


public Task<int> updateTrainer(Trainer trainer) {
    string sql = "update trainer set trainer_name = @tname where trainer_id = @tid";
    return  InvokeAsync(connection => connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, param: new { tname = trainer.trainer_name, tid = trainer.trainer_id }));
}
```